# Assignment with constraints: how to generate possibilities efficiently?

Tags: python, python-itertools

I have a cost matrix linking N0 workers to N1 tasks. All assignments are possible if they satisfy a constraint: (1) there is at least one worker assigned to each task, (2) the last worker can be assigned to an arbitrary number of tasks, and (3) the last task can be assigned to an arbitrary number of workers.

I would like to generate all configurations which satisfy this constraint. I found one way to do this which is very inefficient. Any guidance is appreciated.

edit:

For example, a cost matrix could be

```
costs = np.random.random((3,4))
```

Then I need to find all possible configurations satisfying the constraint. One would be (the last worker can be assigned to more than one task)

```
config = [(0,0),(1,1),(2,2),(2,3)]
```

another would be (the last task is assigned to an arbitrary number of workers)

```
config = [(0,3),(1,3),(2,3),(2,3),(2,0),(2,1),(2,2)]
```

So what I need is all possible lists of tuples linking row to column which satisfy (1) each row links to at least one column, (2) the last row can link to an arbitrary number of columns, and (3) the last column can link to an arbitrary number of rows

Edit #2: 
I believe this is an appropriate generator. Consider that the cost matrix has infinite values which should be ignored. Then the set of all allowed links is

```
n0,n1 = costs.shape
links = []
for i in range(n0):
    for j in range(n1):
        if not np.isinf(costs[i,j]): 
            links.append((i,j))

def filterfn(config):
    # (1) each row but the last should be represented in the config 
    cond1 = set(l[0] for l in config if l[0]!=n0-1) == set(range(n0-1))
    # (2) each column but the last should be represented in the config 
    cond2 = set(l[1] for l in config if l[1]!=n1-1) == set(range(n1-1))
    # (3) each row but the last should be represented exactly once 
    cond3 = len(set(l[0] for l in config if l[0]!=n0-1))==len([l[0] for l in config if l[0]!=n0-1])
    # (4) each column but the last should be represented exactly once
    cond4 = len(set(l[1] for l in config if l[1]!=n1-1))==len([l[1] for l in config if l[1]!=n1-1])

    return cond1 and cond2 and cond3 and cond4 

configs = []  
for r in range(max(s0,s1),s0+s1):
    r_configs  = itertools.combinations(links,r)
    r_configs = filter(lambda config: filterfn(config), r_configs)
    configs.extend(list(r_configs))
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you [edit] your question to include the code that you believe to be inefficient. Read more about how to create a [mcve].

Comment: What kind of size is your problem?

Comment: N0,N1 are of order 10, but this optimization problem needs to be repeated hundreds of thousands of times.

Comment: Please present a sample case and your current solution.  This should clarify the problem.

Comment: There are hundreds of thousands of distinct _problems_ like this that need to be optimised?

Comment: yes. This is for linking trajectories between frames of identified objects.

Comment: What are the benefits of assigning multiple workers to a task? Are we only trying to generate configurations or do they need to have low cost? I can't be very specific, but [backtracking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtracking) might be an effective approach, at least for candidate generation. Some mapping between permutations and worker assignments could work, but I would need to see some of your solution code to better understand those 3 conditions you listed.

Comment: assignment of multiple workers to the last task represents the death of particles between video frames. 

Assignment of multiple tasks to the last worker represents the birth of particles between video frames.

I will clean up the generator I have and post it shortly, thanks!

Comment: Rather than focusing on ways to perform this brute-force search more quickly, it sounds like you should be looking for ways to tackle your underlying problem without performing a brute-force search.

Comment: Actually many elements of the cost matrix will be set to infinity: when these are ignored it will make the size of the brute force search entirely reasonable, if I can get an efficient generator for the possible assignments satisfying the constraint

Comment: The number of assignments satisfying the constraint is approximately factorial. Is it reasonable to use something like [this](http://physics.nyu.edu/grierlab/methods/node8.html) to work with smaller problems and have better asymptotic performance?

Comment: Your constraints don't actually care about what the elements of your cost matrix are. You'll still generate all those infeasible solutions and have to go through them one by one, throwing them out.

Comment: @HansMusgrave yes I plan to do something very similar. The generated possibilities should (eventually) be pre-filtered using the cost matrix. I'm hoping to learn from this post a way around over-generating and filtering the infeasible solutions. In fact (i,j) will only be an allowed link if costs[i,j] is not inf

Comment: @kevinkayaks That's an important detail that should probably be included in the original question.

Comment: my assumption is that it'd be easy to implement the additional constraint that all costs are not inf if I had a generator which did not rely on a posteriori filtering of infeasible configurations

Comment: @HansMusgrave I modified the code to factor in this aspect. However the problem remains that I have no way to generate the allowed configurations without filtering all possibilities